# Persistence.xml file for Hibernate JPA and Mysql

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm finding it difficult to find an up-to-date and clear explanation of how the persistence.xml should look and what it needs to contain. What would your typical persistence.xml file look like for the following:

- Provider: Hibernate implementation of JPA
- Mysql database
- DB name: hibernatetest
- username: root
- password: 12345
- databases url: localhost port 3306

and for the sake of simplicity say that my Entity class that needs to be persistent is located at com.example.MyClass

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

here is an basic persistance.xml example :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa">
        <class>com.example.MyClass</class>
    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

You can find more details about it here :
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html

Comment: Thanks @Hejwo I actually have read that tutorial in their docs, but what comes in between the <persistence-unit> tags? The '...' doesn't help me much

Comment: Path to your classes. I've updated answer with better example.